# Access to Google Maps route optimisation API

Tags: google-maps, windows-services

I am writing a Windows service to get optimised route.
From Javascript I can use `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` which provides optimised route, but from a web service point of view I didn't find equivalent method.

Is it possible to access the API from the server side?

Comment: Do you mean server-side as in within your Windows service? Or at Google's servers? What server technology are you using for your Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

According the [Google help](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints):

> By default, the `Directions` service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass **`optimize:true`** as the **first argument** within the waypoints parameter to allow the `Directions` service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order. (This optimization is an application of the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).)
>
> If you instruct the Directions service to optimize the order of its waypoints, their order will be returned in the waypoint_order field within the routes object. The waypoint_order field returns values which are zero-based.
>
> The following example calculates a road trip route from Adelaide, South Australia to each of South Australia's main wine regions using route optimization.

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=`**`optimize:true`**`|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false`

> Inspection of the calculated route will indicate that the route is calculated using the following waypoint order:

```
"waypoint_order": [ 1, 0, 2, 3 ]
```